# Spring 3.1.2 dependency not resolved

Tags: spring, maven

I'm unable to update my spring framework version from 3.0.1 to 3.1.3.

this is the error I'm getting when installing by mvn.

```
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/org.springframework.core/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.core-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/org.springframework.core/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.core-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    [WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:org.springframework.core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-tx/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-tx/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-tx/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 3.5 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-tx/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.0 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-context/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 5.9 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-context/maven-metadata.xml (3 KB at 3.6 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 7.8 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 2.2 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-core/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 4.7 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-core/maven-metadata.xml (3 KB at 2.8 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-expression/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-expression/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-expression/maven-metadata.xml (759 B at 4.4 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-expression/maven-metadata.xml (831 B at 1.2 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 8.0 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 2.2 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-tx/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-tx/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-tx/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 4.6 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/spring-tx/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.7 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/org.springframework.beans/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/org.springframework.beans/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    [WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:org.springframework.beans:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/org.springframework.context/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/org.springframework.context/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    [WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:org.springframework.context:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/org.springframework.core/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/org.springframework.beans/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    Downloading: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/springframework/org.springframework.context/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/org.springframework.core/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/org.springframework.beans/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/org.springframework.context/3.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 16.128s
    [INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 08 22:16:08 GMT+05:30 2012
    [INFO] Final Memory: 4M/81M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project commons: Could not resolve dependencies for project HFC:commons:jar:1.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:org.springframework.core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE, org.springframework:org.springframework.beans:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE, org.springframework:org.springframework.context:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE: Could not find artifact org.springframework:org.springframework.core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE in repository.springframework.maven.release (http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release) -> [Help 1]
```

My pom.xml is like [this](https://gist.github.com/4241054)

What am I missing here.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a wrong artifactId.

You should use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

See [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-core%7C3.1.3.RELEASE%7Cjar).